# Celery logs to Papertrail

Tags: python, celery, papertrail-app

I am building an applicatrion with Flask and Celery and I am trying to send my application logs to Papertrail. This works fine for my regular (synchronous) application logs. The configuration looks like this:

```
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
    import socket


    class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
        hostname = socket.gethostname()

        def filter(self, record):
            record.hostname = ContextFilter.hostname
            return True


    f = ContextFilter()
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addFilter(f)

    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    )
    syslog = SysLogHandler(address=('<myapp>.papertrailapp.com', <port>))
    syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(syslog)
```

I have tried adding this logger to Celery tasks but all I see is output in sdout and nothing in Papertrail. Does Celery do something to get around the normal logging flow?

I realize Celery has a task-specific logger but I cannot find any documentation on how this could be configured with Celery.

Answer (score 0):

If I read [this](http://oriolrius.cat/blog/2013/09/06/celery-logs-through-syslog/) correctly, the secret is to call the function `redirect_stdouts_to_logger` to send stdout to your `SysLogHandler` instance. [Celery's docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v2.2.5/internals/reference/celery.log.html?highlight=redirect_stdouts_to_logger#celery.log.Logging.redirect_stdouts_to_logger) have more.